# Unity 2D Using Drag To Move Up And Down

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, touch, 2d

I want to transform my game for Android and it's like pong. I want to be able to drag the paddle on a phone. Thanks ahead of time for the help. Here's my oldest code:

```
  using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class MoveRacket : MonoBehaviour {
        public float speed = 30;
        public string axis = "Vertical";

        void FixedUpdate () {
        float v = Input.GetAxisRaw (axis);
          GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ().velocity = new Vector2 (0, v) * speed;



    }
}
```

Heres my old code but it's still not working.

```
   using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class MoveRacket : MonoBehaviour {
    public float speed = 30;
    public string axis = "Vertical";
    public object racket = "Racket";
    public bool touchInput = true;
    public Vector2 touchPos;





    void FixedUpdate () {

        //used to not have anything in parentheses
        float v = Input.GetAxisRaw (axis);
        //GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ().velocity = new Vector2 (0, v) * speed;
        if (Input.touchCount == 1)
        {
            Vector3 wp = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.GetTouch(0).position);
            Vector2 touchPos = new Vector2(wp.x, wp.y);
            if (racket == Physics2D.OverlapPoint(touchPos));
            {
                GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ().velocity = new Vector2 (0, v) * speed;

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Heres my current code that's now fixed.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class MoveRacket : MonoBehaviour {
    public float speed = 30;
    public string axis = "Vertical";
    public object racket = "Racket";
    public bool touchInput = true;
    public Vector2 touchPos;





    void FixedUpdate () {

        //used to not have anything in parentheses
        //float v = Input.GetAxisRaw (axis);
        float v = Input.GetAxisRaw (axis);
        GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ().velocity = new Vector2 (0, v) * speed;
        if (Input.touchCount == 1)
        {
            Vector3 wp = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.GetTouch(0).position);
            Vector2 touchPos = new Vector2(wp.x, wp.y);
            if (Racket.Collider2D == Physics2D.OverlapPoint(touchPos));
            {
                this.transform.position.y = wp.y

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer: Code above is fixed and should be usable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are saying you want to drag , Thus you will need touch 
First you need to check for a touch that if the user is touching the screen then raycast2d to check if he is touching the paddle and use the same logic to keep it at the positon of finger that you used for mouse .

First try it Yourself , use this for hint 
http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/577314/how-to-detect-if-a-sprite-was-object-was-touched-i.html

Thank you

Comment: Thanks for that I will try it out once I have my computer with me.

Comment: I could use your help now. I have tried it out myself but I'm not sure what's relevant to me considering I'm only moving y and also I'm having errors if you have some time I would like help fixing my errors. Thanks ahead of time

Comment: ok dont use the rigidbody component just use this in your second if statement :

this.transform.position = new vector3(wp.x,wp.y,0);

now make sure if you dont want the y position to change then use this.tranform.position.y instead of wp.y

tell me the errors and tell if the touch is working or not ?

Comment: Re edited and stated current errors above thanks for the help.